# Segfault from hflip

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, flip, fault

For some reason when I run this code I get a segfault.  What it does is reads a PGM file from input and flips it horizontally.

Here is what I believe is the offending code:

```
for (i = pixels.size()-1; i = 0; i--){ // this loop takes the final value of the original vector and puts it into the first spot in the new hflip vector, and continues onwards
    flippy.push_back(pixels[i]);
}

cout << "P2" << endl << numColumns << " " << numRows << endl << "255" << endl;
while (p < pixTotal){
    for (int z = 0; z < numRows; z++){
        cout << flippy[p] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    p++;

}
```

Comment: Please include a short, self-contained example.  You haven't posted enough (what is `flippy` defined as?  if you run in a debugger, where does it segfault?)

Comment: I have two vectors.  One is called pixels and the other is called flippy.  The goal is to take pixels and have flippy be the reverse of pixels.

Comment: For example if I give it the input
P2
3 3
255
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
The output should be 
P2
3 3
255
3 2 1
6 5 4
9 8 7

EDIT: err I thought there would be spaces.  Imagine that as a 3 x 3 matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the vector `pixels` represents each row in your matrix. Then to flip all values in the vector, you can simply use `std::reverse_copy` like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> flippy;
flippy.resize(pixels.size());
std::reverse_copy(pixels.begin(), pixels.end(), flippy.begin());
```

You need to do this for each row. You can then output each flipped row after each reverse so that the vector 'flippy' only represents the current row in operation.

Answer (score 1):

You have

> for (i = pixels.size()-1; i = 0; i--)

the middle should be

> i>=0

not

> i=0